# Unable to route using spring TCP integration

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

I have created inbound and outbound  adapters for TCP integration and following is the given configuration.

```
<beans:description>
    Uses conversion service and collaborating channel
    adapters.
</beans:description>

<context:property-placeholder />




<!-- Client side -->

<gateway id="gw"
    service-interface="com.project.configuration.ACDGateway"
    default-reply-timeout="20000" default-request-channel="input"
    default-reply-channel="gatewayChannel" />

<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client" type="client"
    host="10.90.7.31" port="42027" single-use="false"
    serializer="MessageSerializerDeserializerService" deserializer="MessageSerializerDeserializerService"
    so-timeout="10000" />

<publish-subscribe-channel id="input" />

<ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outAdapter.client"
    order="1" channel="input" connection-factory="client" /> <!-- Collaborator -->

<beans:bean id="MessageSerializerDeserializerService"
    class="com.project.service.impl.MessageSerializerDeserializerService" />

<ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inAdapter.client"
    channel="recieve" connection-factory="client" /> <!-- Collaborator -->
<channel id="recieve" />

<header-enricher input-channel="recieve"
    output-channel="gatewayChannel">
    <header name="replyChannel"
        value="gatewayChannel"/>
</header-enricher>
<channel id="gatewayChannel" />
```

When I run it I message gets send but when response is received at inbound adapter then following exception occurs

no output-channel is  available in header.

Then I added one processing element to add that header using header-enricher. After this I am getting

```
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.transformedBeanName(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1090)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:88)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.resolveDestination(AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.java:73)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.send(AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.java:67)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:300)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.send(AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:300)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add `gatewayChannel` as the reply channel header; the `replyChannel` header is specific to each message and the `gatewayChannel` is bridged to it for each message. You are bridging the replyChannel to itself; hence the stack overflow.

You can't use channel adapters here; you must use an outbound gateway instead, so the framework can maintain the `replyChannel` header.

The [tcp-client-server-multiplex sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex) shows one way of how to achieve a similar result using channel adapters, by saving off the `replyChannel` and correlating the reply, but it's really much simpler to use a gateway instead.

Comment: Thanks for that but when I don't add that header then I get no no output-channel is available in header exception.

Comment: The `replyChannel` header is used by the `gw` gateway to correlate replies to requests. You have to save off that header from the outbound message, when the reply is received, figure out which request it was for and restore its `replyChannel` header. As I said, if you use a tcp outbound gateway instead of channel adapters, the framework will take of all that for you.